# VueJS/Vuetify: Change colwidth with animation/transition

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, transition

this is my app component:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col :cols="dynamicCol">
            <worldmap></worldmap>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import WorldMap from "./components/WorldMap";

export default {
  props: {
    source: String
  },
  components: {
    worldmap: WorldMap
  },
  computed: {
    changeDynamicCol() {
      return this.$store.state.lineData.data.length;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    changeDynamicCol(value) {
      if (value > 0) {
        this.dynamicCol = 9;
      }
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    dynamicCol: 12,
    drawer: null
  }),
  created() {
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true;
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

My App starts with an empty array and when I receive data, the first container small shrink from a width of 12 to 9. The code itself works fine, however the chart inside reacts to changes in the viewport, so get´s currently just cut off. In general it looks much better when this is animated.

Does anyone know if and how I can change the width of `v-col` with a transition or other animation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use watchers in wrong way.
Here I show how I see your case, but I don't sure if it works fine.
If you have more question, I can answer in comments

```js
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col :cols="columnCount">
            <worldmap></worldmap>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import WorldMap from "./components/WorldMap";
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  props: {
    source: String
  },
  components: {
    worldmap: WorldMap
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      lineData: state => state.lineData.data.length
    }),
    columnCount() {
      if (this.lineData > 0) {
      return 9
      }
      return 12
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: yes you are right. Your solution is the way to go. But unfortunately it does not solve my original problem ;-)

Comment: Did you try build-in vue <transition> ?